# How to give a label inside a custom table view cell padding and rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image: Storyboard]

I'm trying to make the labels that say '10' and 'in progress' rounded and have a little padding around the text. I've tried the usual .cornerRadius = 5 stuff but it doesn't like that this cell is repeated or generated when more fields are added to the table.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

I tried in this way and it worked. May this help you.

### Step:

Create a count label i.e `10` and apply constraint as width and height equal `(width = 30 and height 30)`

use the code to make it round:

```
        cell.lblCount.layer.cornerRadius = cell.lblCount.frame.height/2
        cell.lblCount.clipsToBounds = true
```

Create a `inprogress` label and apply constraint as 
`height` and width with some value that fits label properly and then set `relation` as `Greater than or equal to`

Make it round using below code

```
        cell.lblProgress.layer.cornerRadius = cell.lblProgress.frame.height/2
        cell.lblProgress.clipsToBounds = true
```

It looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `masksToBounds`

```
yourLabel.layer.cornerRadius = valueYouNeed
yourLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

To add padding around the count number you can use width constraint - connect it from storyboard and change it programmatically:

```
class CountLabel: UILabel {
    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var countWidthConst: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var count: Int? {
        didSet {
            guard let count = count else {return}
            countLabel.text = "\(count)"

            let maximumLabelSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 300)
            let expectedLabelSize: CGSize = countLabel.sizeThatFits(maximumLabelSize)
            countWidthConst.constant = expectedLabelSize.width + 10
        }
    }
}
```

For corners see the [@King.lbt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61952740/2149779) answer.